# Video not loading/html5

Tags: html, web, html5-video

I have a problem that is driving me nuts and I don’t know what else to do.  I purchased the template “Formula” from pixelarity dot com. In the demo, that site has a video playing on a loop in the background. However, the download version has a different video (named banner) for the background. I copied the video I want to play to the images folder (in .mp4 and webm formats) and updated the code as seen below with the name of my video “forwes” however it does not load when I preview the page (it still plays the video that comes with the download.

Any ideas why it doesn’t play when the page is loaded?  Keep in mind, I am a noob at web design and coding

Thanks!

exclude the file extension. The template will automatically
                    generate a multi-format*  tag on platforms that support background videos, and simply skip the
                    step on those that don't (falling back on whatever you've set as the background image).

```
                * Your video must be offered in both .mp4 and .webm formats to work everywhere.
            -->
                <section id="banner" data-video="images/forwes">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <header>
                            <h1>Our Business Name</h1>
                            <p>W we will repair your computers, phones, printers and all other electronic devices. <br />  We provide both in-store support as well as provide full service, onsite IT support for businesses. Contact us for your free consultation today!.</p>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li><a href="#" class="button special big">Get Started</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#one" class="more">Learn More</a>
                </section>
```

Comment: You have to need add correct `video` and then `source` tag for video playing with specific `ogg`  ,  `webm` and `mp4` format I added example on answer..............

Answer (score 0):

Try this With Correct video format and Tags

```css
.container{
margin: 30px auto;
display:block;
max-width:1200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video class="video" poster="" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
            <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
            <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </source>
            <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
            </source>
            <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.ogv" type="video/ogg">
            </source>
        </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working...I just needed to close and reopen my browser...smh

Comment: You can also control video play, pause & more by followed this link
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK